# Show my app logo in google driving directions screen

Tags: android, google-maps, driving-directions

As per [Google Maps APIs terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions)   we can not use real-time navigation or route guidance in our app. We have to navigate to google maps to achieve this functionality. But how does ola and uber apps shows their logo on google driving directions screen?

Answer (score 0):

I thought ola,uber icon in google directions screen is related to google maps. I come know it is a [FLOATING FACE BUBBLE ON HOME SCREEN](https://droidqd.wordpress.com/2015/01/07/how-to-make-a-floating-face-bubble-on-home-screen-in-android/).